# Chakra UI not loading Images locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I am having some difficulties loading local images using Chakra UI with Next.js.

```js
<Image src="./homepage/footer/Black.svg" />
```

This is the folder structure

[image: 1]

In my console:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2):

instead of directly referencing image path, try variable import like below ( i have imported my image as logo )

```
import { Box, Image, VStack } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import logo from './../../assets/images/xyz.png';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Box minH="100vh" className="hero-gradient">
      <VStack>
        <Image src={logo} alt="logo" />
      </VStack>
    </Box>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the public folder in the root at the same level as src folder.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image src="/homepage/footer/Black.svg" />
```

Just do "/" to access images in public folder